# Trying to add a variable number of nested tags in "tag_keys" input plugin in telegraf

Tags: arrays, json, telegraf

I am trying to correctly tag certain nested tags withing arris in json data using the telegraf input plugin.

If I specify them manually I can do it without issue, problem is depending on the server the number of entries with these tags can vary, as you will see telegraf names them like "xxxx_number_yyyy" where the first tag number is 0, second is one and so on.

So, for json code like:

```
{
    "body": {
        "item": {
            "name": "mydatasource",
            "type": "Generic",
            "instances": [
                {
                    "server": "server1",
                    "state": "Running",
                    "connectionsTotalCount": 20
                },
                {
                    "server": "server2",
                    "state": "Running",
                    "connectionsTotalCount": 46
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And the input config in telegraf like:

```
[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = ["command that extracts data in json format"]
  data_format = "json"
  json_query = "body.item"
  tag_keys = ["name","WANT TO ADD INSTANCE_#_SERVER HERE WITHOUT SPECIFYING THEM MANUALLY"]
  json_string_fields = ["type","instances_?_state"]
```

And the output of telegraf like:    `exec_command,host=myhost.example.com,name=mydatasource,instances_0_connectionsTotalCount=20,instances_0_server="server1",instances_0_state="Running",instances_1_connectionsTotalCount=46,instances_1_server="server2",instances_2_state="Running" 1598295890000000000`

As you can see, in this case there are two, so I could easily have:

```
tag_keys = ["name","instances_0_server","instances_1_server"]
```

Problem is this must work for dozens of different configurations and some can have dozens of servers I would like to add tag_keys with such pattern automatically, I tried wildcards but do not seem to work with tag_keys.

Any ideas how to solve this?